# How to fix css in django cycle?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I want to do div titleblog and do magrin-top:100px,but it isnt working in django cycle..Idk why.I tried to do <a class='titleblog',but it wasnt working). P.S css file is attached at html file.CSS file is working,because navigation panel is displaying.

blog.html

```
<div class="titleblog">
{% for i in objects  %}
<a href="{{i.id}}">{{i.titleblog}}</a>
<b>{{i.message | lower}}</b>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

home.css

```
.titleblog{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
{% for i in objects  %}
<div class="titleblog">
    <a href="{{i.id}}">{{i.titleblog}}</a>
    <b>{{i.message | lower}}</b>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried to do it :/

Comment: I created new  css file,it worked! Thanks you